# Procedural Programming Loops

Tags: loops, procedural-programming

I want to clarify a few things about loops in procedural programming. So, I'm doing a unit on procedural programming in my IT course at sixth form and we need to write about three different types of loops, these are "Fixed for loop", "Pre-check while loop" and "Post-check while loop".
I think I have an idea of what these are however, I cannot find sufficient evidence to back up what I think I know.

Fixed for loop:
I think the fixed for loop is what I call the "generic" for loop, I think that this is where you define the counter variable with the for loop e.g.:

```
for (int i=0; i <= 6; i++ ){
     print("Iteration " + i);
}
```

Pre-defined while loop: I think this is a while loop where the counter is defined before the loop itself e.g.:

```
int counter = 0;
while ( i <= 10){
    print ( "Iteration " + i);
    i ++;
}
```

However, if the above is true then I don't understand what a post-defined while loop would be.
If anyone would be kind enough to clarify what each of these loops are, I would much appreciate it.

My question in case it's not clear:
What do the following loops do and how are they defined: "Fixed for loop", "Pre-defined while" and "Post-defined while"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a do...while loop which is basically the same as a while but the condition comes at the end rather than at the start.

```
int i = 0;
do {
    print ( "Iteration " + i);
    i ++;
} while ( i <= 10)
```

It's very useful if you want to perform a block of code **at least** once before checking the condition.

Comment: Ah, thanks! That answered previous comment to Roy Lin :D

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I believe there is a do-while construct. Using Java as example, you have

```
do {
     statement(s)
} while (expression);
```

Where the condition is evaluated "post", or in other words, "after" the first iteration.

Comment: Why would one use this rather than the pre-defined loop then? Is there some kind of benefit/draw back?

Comment: Yea it would be useful sometimes =)
You are 'guaranteed' that this loop will run at least once.
For example, you're reading inputs, you want to read the first one, then you want to ask the user if he/she wishes to input more. oh I didnt see that this has already been answered =(